# sas hash inside macro

Tags: hash, macros, sas

I'd like to create a function that uses hash. The table that is being hashed has 3 columns: Age, Sex, a. I'd like to use a macro in the following way:

1. Define macro before data step:

   ```
   %macro hashfind(age, sex) ;
   rc=tab.find(key: &age, key: &sex );
   %LET p=a ;
   %PUT p;
   %mend;
   ```
2. Open data step, 
   Define hash as following:

   ```
   if _n_=1 then
           do;
               declare hash tab();
               rc=tab.definekey('Age');
               rc=tab.definekey('Sex');
               rc=tab.definedata('a');
               rc=tab.definedone();

               do until (eof1);
                   set work.tab end=eof1;
                   rc=tab.add();
                   put rc;
               end;
   end;
   ```
3. Use the macro in data step in the following way:
4. ```
   abc=%hashfind(30, 'M') ;
   ```

this way the "abc" value is always equal 1. That's not correct with the table. However after I execute the macro and assign this value outside of macro abc=a which is correct value.

To sum it up: what can I do to use whole hash inside macro? (I will extend the macro in the future so it's a necessity.)

Or: Does anyone know how to define a function, that uses hashes in the way I'd like? Using PROC FCMP is not an option, because hashing in PROC FCMP defined functions is not available in SAS 7.1 which I'm using.

Comment: Your SAS version cannot be correct, that's probably your EG version? Use %put &sysver.; to see your SAS version in the log.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the %let statement and %put statement in your macro. Can you explain the purpose of these?

Answer (score 1):

If you call your macro like `%hashfind(30,'M')` rather than `abc=%hashfind(30,'M');` it should work.

When you call it the second way, your SAS DATA step code becomes `abc=rc=tab.find(key: 30, key: 'M');`  That is valid code, and will assign 1 as the value of abc because rc probably has a value of 1 from add() and the find() returns 1 (assuming the key is found).

If you want to specify the name of the data step variable to hold the return code, in this simple case you can change your macro definition to be:

```
%macro hashfind(age, sex) ;
tab.find(key: &age, key: &sex )
%mend;
```

I removed the rc= and the semicolon at the end.  That makes it more function-like. 
You could then call as `abc=%hashfind(30,'M');`

I skipped over discussing your macro %let and %put statements, because I'm not sure what you are trying to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

I created this macro to make the code a bit more user friendly. The way it's written only puts the found variables in the log but it should be fairly easy to modify that.

The macro has 4 arguments: the key(s), the variable you want to find, the input data set, and the value you want to find.

```
%macro hashfind(byvars, findvars, inset, find);

%let data_key = %trim(&byvars);
%let data_key = %sysfunc(tranwrd(&data_key,%str( ), %str(",")));
%let findvars = %trim(&findvars);

data _NULL_;
if 0 then set &inset;

if _N_ = 1 then do;
   declare hash tab(dataset: "&inset.");

   rc = tab.DefineKey  ("&data_key.");
   rc = tab.DefineData ("&findvars.");
   rc = tab.DefineDone ();
end;

&byvars = "&find.";
rc = tab.find();
put &findvars=;

run;

%mend;
```

The macro can then be called as follows:

```
%hashfind(key1 key2 key3 etc, var, dataset, value);
```

This should probably get you a good start, hope it helps.

Comment: Little thoughts: would be good to declare &data_key %local, and looks like it will only work with one byvar that is a character var (otherwise the assignment statement would fail). Also, is this a useful macro (or could it become one?). As is, it seems like a long way to go to generate the equivalent of a DATA step with a where statement. Essentially it is: data want; set have; where &where; run;

Comment: You're right, the way its written now it will only work with one byvar but with some creativity this can be fixed. Also, was to the goal to replace a DATA step with a where statement? It was my understanding that OP was just looking for a find macro but I may be mistaken. Creating a subset of the data set can probably be accomplished by iterating over the input data set, the way it is now will only return the first record. I'm not sure if doing this provides any benefit over a data step with a where statement.